# PHP Multiple Mod Rewrite Rule For AMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amp-html

I'am having trouble with below php rewrite mode code, someone coded that website in past, everything is complicated. All cms goes from index.php?goto string.

Now I want to have amp pages something like,

/amp/blog.amp.php?catidx=how-to-fix-misshapen-teeth

/amp/blog/topic.html, I tried with this code but didnt work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^(.+)/amp/blog.amp.php?catidx=$"
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/amp/blog/$1.html"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)/amp/blog/$" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/amp/blog.amp.php?catidx=$1"  [L]
```

*** Existing Htaccess Code ***

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine on
ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)$  index.php?goto=$1&catidx=$2&cat_idx=$3&cat_idx2=$4 [L,NC]

ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)$    index.php?goto=$1&catidx=$2&cat_idx=$3 [L,NC]

ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)$  index.php?goto=$1&catidx=$2 [L,NC]

ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-0-9]+)$ index.php?goto=$1&mailsuccess=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html?) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(?:php|html?)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
[L,NC]
```

I will be really happy if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted these because they were overwriting everything.

```
ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)$  index.php?goto=$1&catidx=$2&cat_idx=$3&cat_idx2=$4 [L,NC]

ReWriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)/([a-z\-0-9]+)$    index.php?goto=$1&catidx=$2&cat_idx=$3 [L,NC]
```

And added this code; everything works like a charm.

```
ReWriteRule ^amp/blog/([a-z\-0-9]+).amp.html$   amp/blog.amp.php?catidx=$1 [L,NC]
```